# Need to copy recordset row to a table in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm a novice when it comes to coding.

The issue I am trying to solve is that I want take a linked spreadsheet report with blank rows, and different report information (report criteria, report filters, etc.) and filter out only the rows I need.

There are two identifiers in the spreadsheet that I am targeting to find the rows they are on then find the difference between those two rows to create a loop.

My logic I'm trying to follow is:

Find "Profit Center"
Find "Subtotal"
Take the difference between those two row numbers
Copy the information in the rows between Profit center and Subtotal into a different table by using the difference between the two rows as the times to loop.
Assign the current profit center to a field in the new table

I'm stuck on the part of copying the information in the row to a new table but also targeting which row I am trying to copy.

```vb
Private Sub CaseFunctions(Option_Group)
    Select Case Option_Group
        Case 1301
            MsgBox "Option 1 Selected", vbOKOnly
        Case 1302
            Dim TenderFile_RST As Recordset
            Set DB = CurrentDb
            Set TenderFile_RST = DB.OpenRecordset("Tender Report")

            Dim K As Integer
            Dim Row1 As Integer
            Dim Row2 As Integer
            Dim M As Integer

            K = 0
            M = 0

            Dim Str1 As String
            With TenderFile_RST
                TenderFile_RST.FindFirst "[F1] LIKE '*Profit Center:*'"
                    If TenderFile_RST.NoMatch Then
                        MsgBox "No Profit Center: Found."
                    Else
                        Do While K < 5
                            'Str1 = TenderFile_RST!F1
                            Row1 = TenderFile_RST.AbsolutePosition
                            TenderFile_RST.FindNext "[F1] LIKE '*Subtotal*'"
                            Row2 = TenderFile_RST.AbsolutePosition
                            DiffRow = Row2 - Row1 - 2
                            TenderFile_RST.FindNext "[F1] LIKE '*Profit Center:*'"
                            K = K + 1
                        Loop
                        MsgBox "Reached End of File"
                    End If                      
            End With

        Case 1303
            MsgBox "Option 3 Selected", vbOKOnly
    End Select

End Sub
```

Not sure what syntax to use (tried Insert Into, recordset.copy, getrows). I always get some sort of error like missing object, syntax error, or expected end of statement. Table of data working with below:

| Tender |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Tendered Business Period Starting 1/18/2023 3:00 AM and Ending 1/19/2023 2:59 AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Grouped by: Profit Center |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sorted by: Quantity |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Selected For: Store = (1); Profit Center = (60) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Profit Center:(60) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Tenders | Quantity | Tender Amount | Change Amount | Tenders Less Change | % of Total | Breakage | Net Tenders | Currency Received |  |
| 2 | Visa | 40 | $60.00 | $60.00 | $60.00 | 62.05% | $0.00 | $60.00 | $60.00 |  |
| 1 | Cash | 27 | $60.01 | $60.01 | $60.01 | 21.50% | $0.00 | $60.01 | $60.01 |  |
| 3 | Master Card | 8 | $60.02 | $60.02 | $60.02 | 11.81% | $0.00 | $60.02 | $60.02 |  |
| 5 | Discover | 3 | $60.03 | $60.03 | $60.03 | 4.08% | $0.00 | $60.03 | $60.03 |  |
| 4 | American Express | 1 | $60.04 | $60.04 | $60.04 | 0.55% | $0.00 | $60.04 | $60.04 |  |
| Subtotal |  | 79 | $0.00 | $0.00 | $0.00 |  | $0.00 | $0.00 | $0.00 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Selected For: Store = (1); Profit Center = (66) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Profit Center:(66) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Tenders | Quantity | Tender Amount | Change Amount | Tenders Less Change | % of Total | Breakage | Net Tenders | Currency Received |  |
| 2 | Visa | 40 | $66.00 | $66.00 | $66.00 | 62.05% | $0.00 | $66.00 | $66.00 |  |
| 1 | Cash | 27 | $66.01 | $66.01 | $66.01 | 21.50% | $0.00 | $66.01 | $66.01 |  |
| 3 | Master Card | 8 | $66.02 | $66.02 | $66.02 | 11.81% | $0.00 | $66.02 | $66.02 |  |
| 5 | Discover | 3 | $66.03 | $66.03 | $66.03 | 4.08% | $0.00 | $66.03 | $66.03 |  |
| Subtotal |  | 79 | $0.00 | $0.00 | $0.00 |  | $0.00 | $0.00 | $0.00 |  |

Comment: You say you want to copy into a 'different table' and later you say 'new table'. Not clear to me where data comes from nor where it should go to. If you have data in Access, why is Excel involved?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. Data comes from a linked spreadsheet and I want to sort through that spreadsheet and append it to an access table that I have in the database so that I can run a query on it later on.

Comment: Would be helpful to work with data. Could you build a table in your question showing representative data? A text table, not an image. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: Online tool to help build markdown table. Can actually copy/paste Access table. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, grabbing a 'batch' of records from recordset and copying all at once to another table is not feasible.

Opening recordset without sort criteria takes for granted records will retrieve in desired order regardless.

This approach relies on consistency of structure for string manipulation. It extracts StartDate, EndDate, StoreID, ProfitCenterID values from complex strings. Make sure you have corresponding fields in destination table. Any variance from sample provided will complicate.

```
Sub CaseFunctions(Option_Group As Long)
Dim db As DAO.Database, rsSrc As DAO.Recordset, rsDes As DAO.Recordset
Dim strStart As String, strEnd As String, strStr As String, strCtr As String
Select Case Option_Group
    Case 1301
        MsgBox "Option 1 Selected", vbOKOnly
    Case 1302
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rsSrc = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Tender Report] " & _
                    "WHERE NOT F1 IS NULL AND F1 <> 'Tender' AND F1 <> 'Subtotal' " & _
                    "AND NOT F1 LIKE '*by:*' AND NOT F1 LIKE 'Profit*'")
        Set rsDes = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE 1=0")
        With rsSrc
            Do While Not .EOF
                Select Case True
                    Case InStr(!F1, "Period") > 0
                        strStart = Mid(Left(!F1, InStr(!F1, " and")), InStr(!F1, "Starting ") + 9)
                        strEnd = Mid(!F1, InStr(!F1, "Ending ") + 7)
                    Case InStr(!F1, "Selected") > 0
                        strStr = Val(Mid(!F1, InStr(!F1, "Store = (") + 9))
                        strCtr = Val(Mid(!F1, InStr(!F1, "Center = (") + 10))
                    Case IsNumeric(Trim(!F1))
                        'save record to table
                        rsDes.AddNew
                        rsDes!StartDate = strStart
                        rsDes!EndDate = strEnd
                        rsDes!StoreID = strStr
                        rsDes!ProfitCenterID = strCtr
                        rsDes!Tenders = !F2
                        rsDes!Quantity = !F3
                        rsDes!TenderAmount = !F4
                        rsDes!ChangeAmount = !F5
                        rsDes!TendersLessChange = !F6
                        rsDes!PctOfTotal = Replace(!F7, "%", "")
                        rsDes!Breakage = !F8
                        rsDes!NetTenders = !F9
                        rsDes!CurrencyReceived = !F10
                        rsDes.Update
                End Select
                .MoveNext
            Loop
            MsgBox "Reached End of File"
        End With
    Case 1303
        MsgBox "Option 3 Selected", vbOKOnly
End Select
End Sub
```

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Thank you, that has gotten me closer. The issue with that now is that I have multiple Profit Centers and Subtotals that I need to insert into my temp table, but only the rows in between the Profit Centers and Subtotals. I added a table for reference. I think the "If !F1 Like "*Subtotal*" Then Exit Do" only allows the first one found to be inserted. Thanks again for the help.